# PaperClip and Rails 4: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

This seems to be an error with Rails 4, it worked with Rails 3, but fails with both 4.1 and 4.2. I created a new test project, with a single model, Post, then added a Paperclip file field, called avatar. Paperclip 4.2.1, by the way.

Here is my test model, which just validates the content type.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar

  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
end
```

The controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  #...
  # Just as generated by Rails, except as below, where I added the avatar field:

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:name, :body, :avatar)
    end
end
```

The _form view

```
<%= form_for(@post, :url => posts_path, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  ...Several lines generated by Rails
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Trying to upload an image generates this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass):                                                 
  paperclip (4.2.1) lib/paperclip/media_type_spoof_detector.rb:63:in `type_from_file_command'              
  paperclip (4.2.1) lib/paperclip/media_type_spoof_detector.rb:50:in `calculated_content_type'             
  paperclip (4.2.1) lib/paperclip/media_type_spoof_detector.rb:42:in `calculated_media_type'               
  paperclip (4.2.1) lib/paperclip/media_type_spoof_detector.rb:30:in `media_type_mismatch?'                
  paperclip (4.2.1) lib/paperclip/media_type_spoof_detector.rb:13:in `spoofed?'                            
  paperclip (4.2.1) lib/paperclip/validators/media_type_spoof_detection_validator.rb:8:in `validate_each'  
  activemodel (4.2.0) lib/active_model/validator.rb:151:in `validate'                                      
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'                                                                  
  activemodel (4.2.0) lib/active_model/validator.rb:148:in `validate'                                      
  paperclip (4.2.1) lib/paperclip/validators.rb:68:in `create_validating_before_filter'
```

I had a poke around. In ...\gems\paperclip-4.2.1\lib\paperclip\helpers, there is a module with this method:

```
def run(cmd, arguments = "", interpolation_values = {}, local_options = {})
  command_path = options[:command_path]
  Cocaine::CommandLine.path = [Cocaine::CommandLine.path, command_path].flatten.compact.uniq
  if logging? && (options[:log_command] || local_options[:log_command])
    local_options = local_options.merge(:logger => logger)
  end
  Cocaine::CommandLine.new(cmd, arguments, local_options).run(interpolation_values)
end
```

It seems to stumble on that last line, and it seems to be because it is looking for the wrong file. Here are the params:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"?", "authenticity_token"=>"gYTVjpqNjHpzZt5aBdpWzHhwZ3V0URFhH/TkRQT5P6qJShmFuauehEdRXtGiNZoSmPmPK5q+F7jOv8VR3B6hTg==", "post"=>{"name"=>"name", "body"=>"body...", "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x86dbbe @original_filename="colour test.png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[avatar]\"; filename=\"colour test.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\RackMultipart20150422-7116-12wd99n.png>, @content_type="image/png">}, "commit"=>"Create Post"}
```

Note that the temporary file starts "RackMultipart" (and this is still there after Rails 4 does its strong parameters thing). However, Cocaine is being sent this:

```
file -b --mime "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\7f220723ebddeeb3a4feff6ec43c42a5150422-7116-1et5e2r-.png"
```

The RackMultipart file exists, the one Concaine is looking for does not. Not surprisingly it objects, saying "bin/rails: No such file or directory -" and returns nil, and hence the error.

By the way, I am aware of this question, but I believe it to be a different issue, as that was a bug in Paperclip, apparently resolved in 2012 (though I am on Windows 7).
[Paperclip on Windows - undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278679/paperclip-on-windows-undefined-method-split-for-nilnilclass)